# Merging Three js meshes with html

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Could someone explain to me how can I position my meshes on site if I have one canvas with position fixed? My canvas has one mesh with custom shaders and it's my animated background, but I want to add other meshes in a different part of my site; but, when I scroll, my camera won't change y coordinates which are good but other objects won't be visible. I'm wondering if there is a way to render somehow other meshes separately and give them custom top, left, etc. values.

```
    export default class Sketch {
  constructor(options) {
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

    this.container = options.dom;
    this.width = this.container.offsetWidth;
    this.height = this.container.offsetHeight;
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
    this.renderer.setSize(this.width, this.height);
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0xeeeeee, 1); 

    this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);


    const fontOpen = new Promise(resolve => {
      new FontFaceObserver("Open Sans").load().then(() => {
        resolve();
      });
    });

    const fontBungee = new Promise(resolve => {
      new FontFaceObserver("Bungee Outline").load().then(() => {
        resolve();
      });
    });

    const fontRoboto = new Promise(resolve => {
      new FontFaceObserver("Roboto Serif").load().then(() => {
        resolve();
      });
    });


    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      70,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.001,
      1000
    );

    // var frustumSize = 10;
    // var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    // this.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( frustumSize * aspect / - 2, frustumSize * aspect / 2, frustumSize / 2, frustumSize / - 2, -1000, 1000 );
    this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 1.3);
    this.camera.fov = 2 * Math.atan(this.height/2)/ 1.3 *(180/Math.PI);
    
    this.time = 0;

    this.isPlaying = true;

    let allDone = [fontOpen,fontBungee,fontRoboto]
    this.currentScroll = 0;
    this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    this.mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

   
    
    Promise.all(allDone).then(()=>{
      this.addObjects();
      this.resize();
      this.render();
      this.setupResize();
    // this.settings();

    })
    
  }



  

  

  settings() {
    let that = this;
    this.settings = {
      progress: 0,
    };
    this.gui = new dat.GUI();
    this.gui.add(this.settings, "progress", 0, 1, 0.01);
  }

  setupResize() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.resize.bind(this));
  }

  resize() {
    this.width = this.container.offsetWidth;
    this.height = this.container.offsetHeight;
    this.renderer.setSize(this.width, this.height);
    this.camera.aspect = this.width / this.height;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  addObjects() {
    let that = this;
    this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      extensions: {
        derivatives: "#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable"
      },
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      uniforms: {
        time: { value: 0 },
        resolution: { value: new THREE.Vector4() },
      },
      // wireframe: true,
      // transparent: true,
      vertexShader: vertex,
      fragmentShader: fragment
    });

    this.geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1.5, 32, 32);

    this.plane = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
    this.scene.add(this.plane);
  }

  stop() {
    this.isPlaying = false;
  }

  play() {
    if(!this.isPlaying){
      this.render()
      this.isPlaying = true;
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.isPlaying) return;
    this.time += 0.005;


    
    this.material.uniforms.time.value = this.time;
    requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }
}

new Sketch({
  dom: document.getElementById("container")
});
```

Comment: That's a lot of information for showing no code. If you show the code, it might be easier to understand.

Comment: @Berthur i added my code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You could follow the three.js [multiple element example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=multi#webgl_multiple_elements).  With appropriate alpha settings, it should provide the effect you're looking for.